# Rails 3: get total number of specific values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to generate statistics for a certain date range. For example, I have a Project model, with a "duration" attribute. The user can select from a menu three different values:

- Academic year
- Semester
- Summer term

This is what I have so far in the searches controller:

```
def index
  unless params[:from].nil? and params[:to].nil?
    @result = Project.where('start_date >= ? AND start_date <= ?', Date.strptime(params[:from], "%m/%d/%Y"), Date.strptime(params[:to], "%m/%d/%Y"))
...
end
```

Which gets me an array of all the projects, but I can't convert that array into statistics.

I want to get a total of the projects that have a duration of Academic year, total that have a duration of Semester and total that have a duration of Summer term.

The code has to be flexible enough that if later I add "One month" to the list of options the code will pick it up.

I had previously done that with amounts, but not with string values: [Rails 3. Get totals from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913671/rails-3-get-totals-from-array)

The result would look something similar to this:

```
** Duration **
Academic year: 12
Semester: 9
Summer term: 5

** Course Disciplines **
Dental: 11
Biomedical: 3
Nursing: 7

** many more other attributes ***
```

Thanks!

Comment: This looks more like a request than a question. What did you try?

Comment: @result.count will give you the count of projects. Refresh your Ruby.

Comment: I already have the total number of projects, what I'm trying to find out is the count of unique values. For example: I have a duration column, how many unique values are there? how many records of each unique value are there?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that simply be finding all Projects where duration = "Semester" and then doing a count on the returned array?

Comment: yes, but I need to get a count of MANY more attributes: course discipline, service hours, interdisciplinary projects, etc

Comment: So write a model query for whatever you need. If you have a specific question where something did not work as expected, we can answer but we cannot predict what you want and write the code for you. Refer to the rails guides on queries - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each instance of @result returns a string (or better yet a symbol) when #duration is called, this should get you started:

```
# Sample data for example, use an OpenStruct to simulate the model
require 'ostruct'
@result = (["Academic year"] * 12 + ["Semester"] * 9 + ["Summer Term"] * 5).map { |a| OpenStruct.new(duration: a) } 

durations = @result.to_a.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |a, p| a[p.duration] += 1; a }
# => {"Academic year"=>12, "Semester"=>9, "Summer Term"=>5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a great select method on the Array class so you can do things like this:

```
a = [1, 3, 10, 20, 50]

results = a.select {|item| item > 3}

puts results

#->[10, 20, 50]
```

Using this you could setup some complex requirements and then just run a count on the resulting array.

Its worth noting that if you have to do this for a lot of items frequently its probably worth storing the stats in another table or system that updates in the background (via resque for example) or on create/update.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
attr_accessor :total
```

To Project model and change your query as follow:

```
 @result = Project.select("duration, count(*) as total").group("duration").where('start_date >= ? AND start_date <= ?', Date.strptime(params[:from], "%m/%d/%Y"), Date.strptime(params[:to], "%m/%d/%Y"))
```